# Dishwasher Leaks

Tags: dishwasher

While running the dishwasher water leaks heavily out of the bottom front. I replaced the seal to no effect. I then noted that while the dishwasher is running there is a lot of standing water in the bottom which is what is running out during operation. When I place the operation in final rinse the water will drain out normally which tells there shouldn't be a clog. I have had this dishwasher for many years. Is it possible the pump is just not getting rid of the water as it should?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Maybe the water level sensor is broken, so it fills itself too far? Hard to tell from here...

Comment: I had a water level sensor problem a long time ago and my dish washer leaked, after replacing when I put it back in the back feet jumped several positions and it was worse , finally figured it out the back was up to high, so if you have self adjusting feet be aware to keep the machine level as you push it back in. +

Comment: We had this problem a few years ago.  We switched soap brands and now use Finish.  The leaks stopped.

Answer (score 1):

A leaking dishwasher is a common problem. Dishwashers will leak due to a problem with the water inlet valve that isn't connected properly or just faulty, unfortunately these cannot be repaired and need to be replaced. There are times when the door seal is ripped or cracked and that would be the reason for the leaking dishwasher.

Water Inlet Valve: The water inlet valve allows water to flow into the dishwasher. It can become stuck in the open position letting water to continue to flow.

Wash Arm Assemblies: There is a lower wash arm, centre wash arm and upper wash arm assembly. These parts is where the water sprays out to clean your dishes. If there are any cracks in these arm assemblies then water may be spraying directly against the dishwasher door causing a leak. Check to make sure the wash arm assemblies are not loose by making sure all the screws are tight.

Door Seal: Inspect the main door seal for any evidence of cracks or wear. Watch the door seal closely while the dishwasher runs to inspect it for leaks.

Answer (score 0):

I had a leak because the water supply line used a **garden hose type connector**.   The rubber washer had deteriorated.   I replaced it with a silicon washer.